# Template::Error (undefined method `specification_items_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, naming-conventions

i have a line in routes.db:

```
resources :specificationItems
```

**My specification_item.rb model**:

```
class SpecificationItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :amount, :item_id, :price, :specification_id, :total
    belongs_to :specification
    belongs_to :item
end
```

**specification_items.rb Controller:**

```
class SpecificationItemsController < ApplicationController
    def new

        @specificationItem = SpecificationItem.new(:specification_id => params[:specification_id])
    end

  def create

    @specificationItem = SpecificationItem.new(params[:specificationitem])

    if @specificationItem.save
        respond_to do |format|
        format.html {
            flash[:success] = "Запись добавлена успешно"
            redirect_to @specificationItem      
        }         
        format.js
        end
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

    def show
        @specificationitems = SpecificationItem.where("specification_id = ?", @specification.id.to_s)
    end

    def index
        @specificationitems = SpecificationItem.all
    end

end
```

with this line in specification/show i calling a new action of `specification_item` :

```
  <%= link_to "Add item to spec", new_specificationItem_path(:specification_id =>@specification.id), id: "new_item", remote: true %>
```

this is a js action in new.js.erb

```
  $('#new_item').hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>')
```

partial _form.html.erb:

```
  <%= form_for @specificationItem, remote: true do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
        <%= f.label :item_id, "Товар" %>
        <%= f.text_field :item_id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :specification_id %>

   </div>
   </div>

<%= f.submit "Сохранить", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

it raise error :

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `specification_items_path' for #<#<Class:0xb5b708e4>:0xb5b6e5e4>):
    1: <%= form_for @specificationItem, remote: true do |f| %>
    2:     <div class="row">
    3:      <div class="span6 offset3">
    4:              <%= f.label :item_id, "Товар" %>
  app/views/specification_items/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_specification_items__form_html_erb___537109236__624411928'
  app/views/specification_items/new.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_specification_items_new_js_erb___211974400__624460778'
```

I suspect that error belongs to naming conventions, but can,t recognize it.
sorry for my newbie question and wrong English

Thank you!

Comment: can you tell us the related section in your `routes.rb`?

Comment: resources :specificationItems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `rake routes` it will show all available paths.
Also I've noticed that you wrote `resources :specificationItems`, due to convenyion it should be `resources :specification_items`.